# How do I convert from seconds to minutes using this library?

Tags: c++, c++14, units-of-measurement

I have a [program](https://repl.it/repls/PreemptivePepperyCarriers) that uses this popular [library](https://github.com/nholthaus/units), however I am struggling to use it to convert from seconds to minutes

The following code...

```
#include <iostream>

#include "units.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        long double one = 1.0;

        units::time::second_t seconds;
        units::time::minute_t minutes(one);

        seconds = minutes;

        std::cout << "1 minute is " << seconds << std::endl;
    }


    {
        long double one = 1.0;

        units::time::second_t seconds(one);
        units::time::minute_t minutes;

        minutes = seconds;

        std::cout << "1 second is " << minutes << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

produces...

```
1 minute is 60 s
1 second is 1 s
```

however, I would have expected it to produce...

```
1 minute is 60 s
1 second is .016666667 m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library offers a `units::convert` method, check the doc [here](http://nholthaus.github.io/units/group___conversion.html#gaa03816ee32bb44ddbd6bc866ef89b231).

Here's a working snippet:

```
    long double one = 1.0;

    units::time::second_t seconds(one);
    units::time::minute_t minutes;

    minutes = seconds;

    std::cout << "1 second is " << minutes << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1 second is "
              << units::convert<units::time::seconds, units::time::minutes>(seconds)
              << std::endl;
```

For more, I suggest searching in the [doc](http://nholthaus.github.io/units/index.html).

Comment: That's great! is it bug that prevents my approach from working?

Comment: It might be since the `units::time::minute_t` print is always expressed as seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the library you are using, but C++11 added the `std::chrono::duration` class that seems to be able to do what you want:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    {
        std::chrono::minutes minutes(1);
        std::chrono::seconds seconds;

        seconds = minutes;

        std::cout << "1 minute is " << seconds.count() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::chrono::seconds seconds(1);
        using fMinutes = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::minutes::period>;
        fMinutes minutes = seconds;

        std::cout << "1 second is " << minutes.count() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the default `std::chrono::minutes` uses an integer counter, and thus reports that 1 second is 0 minutes. That is why I define my own float-minutes.

In any case, the above program produces the following output:

```
1 minute is 60
1 second is 0.0166667
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am using this library for its support of many different unit types. I used time by way of an example.